# Quartz.net in Azure: "tables without a clustered index are not supported" when deleting a job

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, quartz.net

I spent the better part of the day trying to get Quartz.net to run in an Azure worker role. It uses an SQL Azure instance as its persistent store.

The configuration I've got is this the following:

```
quartz.jobStore.type=Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType=Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS
quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString=Server=xxx,1433;Database=xxx;User ID=xxx@xxx;Password=xxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;
quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider=SqlServer-20
```

To create the schema, I used the scripts that came in the Quartz.net zip file. Actually, I tried two of them:

1. [tables_sqlServer.sql](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10231920/tables_sqlServer.sql),
2. [tables_sqlServerCe.sql](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10231920/tables_sqlServerCe.sql)

They were in the Quartz.NET-2.2.1.zip I downloaded. I had to remove `ON [PRIMARY]` in the `ALTER TABLE` statements of the first script in order to get it to work; otherwise it complained about *'Filegroup reference and partitioning scheme' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.'*

The second one worked without modifications.

Whichever script I use to create the schema, Quartz.net throws an error when I try to **delete** a job:

*"Couldn't remove trigger: Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again."*

I'm able to add jobs (I can see the rows being added to the DB) but whenever I try to delete one, Quartz.net throws a fit.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: post the scripts. Personally, I would run it locally (not azure) with sql profiler  to see what happens when I call the delete function on Quartz, to see the actual sql being used. As it says, Azure does not allow creation of tables without a clustered index, so you need to find out what exactly is happening.

Comment: Have a look at Gaurav's work from last year in getting Quartz running on Azure (table storage and not sql) http://gauravmantri.com/2013/01/23/building-a-simple-task-scheduler-in-windows-azure/

Comment: I added the scripts to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated and ran smoke tests for script alterations that should make it work on SQL Azure, the latest script is available here:

https://raw.github.com/quartznet/quartznet/master/database/tables/tables_sqlServer.sql

Comment: Yes, I just found out myself that the problem was a missing clustered primary key on the `QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS` table. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: Thanks @JanVandenbosch that was the same problem I had.

Comment: SQL Azure now supports heaps on V12 servers, so this issue should no longer be a problem. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188029.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396